# Deleting records in MySQL where IDs from two tables match

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, records

I have two tables, `TableA` and `TableB`, and each has a field called `ID`.

I want to delete all the records in `TableA` where the `ID` matches a record in `TableB`.

I try to do this command, but `TableB` is not found

```
DELETE FROM TableA WHERE TableA.id=TableB.id;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't reference TableB on `WHERE` because that table was not joined. But on this case you don't even need a `JOIN`, use this:

```
DELETE FROM TableA WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM TableB)
```

Comment: Does it excecute the subquery for each record or ony once per query?
EX: If i have 100 rows in table 'TableA' does 'SELECT id FROM TableB' run 100 times or 1 time?

Comment: The subquery is executed once, then the result is compared to the `id`s from `TableA`.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider using [foreign key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) so you don't have to manually do these types of operations, rather the database will handle them for you.

For example, if you had a shared id between tableA and tableB, and a delete from tableA occurred, MySQL would handle the delete from tableB for you automatically, and you wouldn't have to worry about joining to other tables that had a FK constraint to tableA.

It could be as simple as:

```
DELETE FROM tableA WHERE id = some_id LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a join

```
DELETE TABLEA FROM TABLEA INNER JOIN TABLEB USING(ID)
```

Big subqueries can be slow if MySQL ends up having to actually materialise the temporary table - definitely worth checking the query plan

Answer (score 1):

How about using an INNER JOIN?  This worked for me in MySQL:

```
DELETE tablea FROM tablea
INNER JOIN tableb
ON tablea.ID = tableb.ID
```